# How to make consecutive calls to pull down paginated data in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, pagination

Upon a button press, I need to pull down paginated data (pulling down pins from Pinterest IOS SDK, the pins are limited to 25 per call), i.e. I need my code to iterate until `responseObject` no longer `.hasnext`.  What's the best way to approach this?  I can press the button over and over to pull it all down, but I want to automate it so there's only 1 button press required.

```
@IBAction func didPressGetPinsButton(sender: UIButton) {



            if self.fetchingMore == false && self.currentResponseObject.hasNext() {


                    self.fetchingMore = true

                    self.currentResponseObject.loadNextWithSuccess({ (nextResponseObject :PDKResponseObject!) -> Void in

                        self.fetchingMore = false
                        self.currentResponseObject = nextResponseObject



                        guard let unwrappedArrayOfPins = nextResponseObject.pins() as? [PDKPin] else {return}

                          for pin in unwrappedArrayOfPins {
                              pins.append(pin) 
                          }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put the action code into a separate function, so that you call it for the first time from the button press, and then you keep re-calling it while .hasNext

```
@IBAction func didPressGetPinsButton(sender: UIButton) {
    actionGetPins()
}

func actionGetPins() {
    // all your code

    if nextResponseObject.hasNext() {
        actionGetPins()
    }
}
```

Depending on how long it takes to get all of the data, you might also want to run the whole function in a background task, but you should at least add a busy indicator to show that there's still work being done.